# ¿Cómo puedo obtener solo las filas siguientes a un id de una tabla en phpMyadmin? solo quiero obtener los datos que están a por delante del id:3

Tags: mysql, sql

| id | nombre_curso |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aritmética |
| 2 | algebra |
| 3 | literatura |
| 4 | historia |
| 5 | física |
| 6 | química |

Comment: ¿No te sirve esto: **`SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE id > 3`**?

Comment: También puede servirte este query:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN(4,5,6,7)` Solo si tienes pocos datos e incluso si deseas consultar ciertos ID.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado. Además, la base de datos es _MySQL_ (según las etiquetas). PHPMyAdmin no tiene relevancia en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias...!! eso me sirve..

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

En SQL dispones de la cláusula `WHERE` para filtrar datos por una condición dada.

Esto es lo que dice el [Manual de Referencia sobre `WHERE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

> The `WHERE` clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions
> that rows must satisfy to be selected. `where_condition` is an
> expression that evaluates to `true` for each row to be selected. The
> statement selects all rows if there is no `WHERE` clause.
>
> In the `WHERE` expression, you can use any of the functions and
> operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (group) functions.
> See [Section 9.5, “Expressions”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html), and [Chapter 12, Functions and Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html).

---

> La cláusula `WHERE`, si se usa, indica la condición o condiciones que
> las filas deben cumplir para ser seleccionadas. `where_condition` es
> una expresión que se evalúa como verdadera para cada fila que se
> seleccione. La declaración selecciona todas las filas si no hay una
> cláusula `WHERE`.
>
> En la expresión `WHERE`, puede usar cualquiera de las funciones y
> operadores que admite MySQL, excepto las funciones agregadas (de
> grupo). Consulte la [Sección 9.5, “Expresiones”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html), y el [Capítulo
> 12, Funciones y operadores](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/functions.html).

Significa que puedes usar `WHERE` con el operador mayor que (`>`) para obtener las filas cuyo `id` sea mayor que `3`:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    nombre_curso
FROM 
    laTabla 
WHERE 
    id > 3;
```